# Отображение диалога как отдельной активити

Tags: android, java

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы диалог открывался на планшете как обычный андроидный диалог, а на телефоне - как отдельная активити? То есть тот же принцип, что и с фрагментами. А то у меня есть диалог со сложным интерфейсом. На планшете выглядит хорошо, а на телефоне нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш случай - это просто отлавливать разрешение экрана и соответственно реагировать на это. Если планшет - показать диалог, если нет - показать активити. Как-то так. Или же, пробовать  как описано [тут](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) Нажатие на фрагмент в случае телефона вызовет активити новое, в случае планшета диалог(то бишь обновит фрагмент).

Конечно, уверен есть и другие способы.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал гораздо проще, а именно эмулировал диалогом активити. Как я понял вопрос в том, что диалог маленький и плохо кажется на экране в зависимости от устройства. Надо тупо развернуть диалог на весь экран, примерно так:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: Это стоит попробовать!

Comment: @Barmaley, почему-то у меня этот способ не заработал. Что представляет из себя `R.layout.my_dialog`? Или в чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: @Дарья R.layout.my_dialog это вёрстка вашего диалога. Автор наглядно показывает, что вызвать метод, который разворачивает диалог на весь экран надо там же, где вы создаёте вёрстку для диалога.